# Add column with numbers from 1 to 7 depending on the numbers of rows of data table

Tags: r, ggplot2, datatable

How can I add a column to my data table (time series) that contains numbers from 1 to 7, depending on the number of rows? **For example:** My data table has 70 rows, then I would like to add a column that lists 10 times the 1, then 10 times the 2 etc. in succession. I need this column to color a plot where I have 7 colors available. The number of columns is always different, so adding the numbers from 1 to 7 should work according to the number of columns.
My data table could look like this for example (but looks always different, as I get the data table from an external server):

```
set.seed(123)
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                      'Power' = rnorm(365, 30, 1), 'Gas' = rnorm(365, 10, 1),
                      'CO2' = rnorm(365, 40, 1), check.names = FALSE)
```

How can I add a new column, which contains (365/7 = 52,14) 52 times the number 1 then 52 times the number 2 ... up to 52 times number 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rep` with `length.out` specified as number of rows in the dataframe.

```
dt.data$new_col <- rep(1:7, length.out = nrow(dt.data))
```

---

If you want the numbers to be 1, 1, 1, ....7, 7, 7 and not 1, 2, 3 `sort` the sequence.

```
dt.data$new_col <- sort(rep(1:7, length.out = nrow(dt.data)))
```

Or

```
dt.data$new_col <- rep(1:7, each = nrow(dt.data)/7, length.out = nrow(dt.data))
```

Comment: The numbers should start with 1 and end with 7, which means that the numbers between 1 and 7 should not be added randomly. First all ones, then all twos, etc. and at the end all 7.

Comment: The numbers are not added randomly. They were assigned as 1, 2, ..7, 1, 2..7 etc. I have updated the answer to include them in increasing sequence.